# How do I detect that all bodies in the world have reached zero velocity?

Tags: box2d, libgdx, jbox2d

I am using the java port of box2d.
I was wondering, is there a way to detect when all the objects in the box2d world have reached 0 velocity? like a callback or something?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a callback for this. But you can still make your own method and deduct it according to each body's velocity. If you allowed sleep, just test if all your bodies are in sleep mode with the `isAwake()` method.